# PHP (IntelliJ/PhpStorm inspection): "Method should be final"

Tags: php, security, inheritance, phpstorm, final

Since a month or something like this the IntelliJ/PhpStorm inspection "Method should be final" is shown on almost any function as a warning. I know I can disable certain inspections I just wonder why they have introduced it?

Definition of a final method in PHP:

> A method is considered a final method if it is prefixed with the final
> keyword. The final methods are the methods that cannot be overridden.
> So, these methods can’t be overridden in child/subclasses.

So why should I actively prevent this on any method? It simply means more work if you have to remove the keyword when creating subclasses. If it is critical that a method is not overridden then of course you add the final keyword, but is there ANY good reason to do this for all methods?

Comment: Maybe that comes from a third-party plugin [jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-69885)

Comment: Could be possible indeed, I have lots of them installed. But then still the question remains if the third-party plugin is suggesting that for any good reason?

Comment: We could really use more context, and maybe a screenshot of the notification--plugins are typically identified: https://i.imgur.com/itobW0v.png

Comment: Checked it and it is from a plugin called "PhpClean".

Comment: So it is not IntelliJ/PHPStorm to blame here, still the question remains if that Inspection makes sense?

Comment: As a general rule, for every single possible class type? It doesn't. In some specific use case? Maybe. Thus the request for further context.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález After doing some research I decided to remove that rule because it harms re-usability of the code and makes extensions more difficult. For security reasons and cleanliness it can make sense to declare some methods final (e.g. annotated API endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

Final in method declaration helps to understand that this method not overridden anywhere.

In latest PHP release core team give us many abilities for make code more strict & clear.

**Yes, you can see if method overridden in IntelliJ / PHPStorm, but if you see code in web browser or in terminal you can't id.**

Also it helpful for make code review. If reviewers see that final was deleted - they pay attention, but if final was not set they see only new method.

So I think that is best practice to make your app classes final by default, or make other methods final if you have only one overridden method.
*Sorry for my bad english.*

Comment: Making methods final might increase security and cleanliness of the code, but it it harms reusability and might make extension maybe unnecessary difficult. So it entirely depends on the app, I guess I will disable that inspection.